# Why is the engine suggesting this move?

Tags: analysis, strategy

```
[FEN "r1bqk1nr/p1ppbppp/1p6/n2P4/8/2N5/PPP1QPPP/R1B1KBNR w KQkq - 3 7"]

1. g4
```

With White to move, the Lichess engine suggests g4 in this position. Can someone explain why it's a good move?

Comment: White to move I assume? Which Engine?

Comment: @IanBush Yes, It's white's move. I analyzed it on lichess.org so I think it's stockfish 12.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Black would like to continue their development with Nf6 and castling short. g4 discourages Nf6; after g5, the knight is forced back. It also prepares Bg2, which protects d5 without giving up the pin on the e-file. The weakening of the kingside apparently isn't too much of a problem; Black isn't developed enough to take advantage of this, and White can always castle queenside.